# Having trouble obtaining Telerik HTML Editor's content using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, html-editor

I have an [editor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/editor) that built as follows:

```
        EditorBuilder builder = context.Html.Telerik().Editor()
                                                      .Name(ID)
                                                      .Encode(false)
                                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = string.Format("width:100%;height:{0}px", height) })
                                                      .Value(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value));

        return builder.ToHtmlString();
```

Everything works as expected.  What I want to do now, is get the contents of the editor to allow the user to "preview" it in another window.  After some searching, I came across `$find(<%=RadEditor.ClientID%>);`, but I am not using this form of generating the editor (and it's in razor).

So, my question is, how do I get at the contents of the editor using jQuery?  `val()` does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik stores the content of the editor using the jQuery data()
method. To access the content of the editor use the following code:

```
var editor = $("#<your editor ID goes here>").data("tEditor");
alert(editor.value());
```

The ID passed to jQuery must match the ID you passed to the
`Html.Telerik().Editor().Name()` function.

The code above only works if you have setup the necessary scripts
for the telerik editor.

For more information please see the [telerik client side api documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/editor/clientsideapi).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm not entirely sure why I missed that page you linked to, but I managed it!